# Visual C++ - Detect if the program is loaded into the Visual Debugger

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a school project, I wanted to know if it is possible to detect if the program is loaded into the Visual Studio debugger, and if it is possible, I want to close the debugger and the app.

Is there a way to do that ? Thanks !

Comment: It is generally considered a bad idea to make program behavior change depending on whether a debugger is attached, because it makes debugging the program much harder. That said, you can use `IsDebuggerPresent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is calling [IsDebuggerPresent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms680345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then exit the application if it returned `true`. This may be enough for a first try.

However, it mainly depends on how good someone is with debugging. A good developer / malware analyst may easily work around such a trick.

You may want to look at [What is your favourite anti-debugging trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573115/what-is-your-favourite-anti-debugging-trick) here on SO for other ideas.